# Creating Chrome Plugin to communicate via TCP/IP

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

We have a web application running in Chrome browser. We need it to connect it via TCP/IP to a network connected device, which would be normally impossible. Our only chance is implementing a Chrome Extension which would be able to create such requests – would this be even possible?

I studied this:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devguide

But I couldn't find any information about accessing hardware from Chrome Extensions. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: what about using WebSocket in your web app? Maybe that is an option. (I'm not sure what you mean by TCP/IP, normally I'd say use a TCP Socket connection)

Comment: We have a device lying on the local network, however the device is not a HTTP server, it will require classical TCP handshakes and so. Is this feasible with websockets?

Comment: Yes that's the point of using WebSockets, just google it. It's like a bidirectional socket connection over tcp, not using the HTTP protocoll)

Comment: Okay if you write it as an answer I will accpet it.

Comment: Another way might be to connect to a Windows VB app, via native messaging, which connects to the device.https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging

Comment: Hi @Vojtěch Did you able to make it out? if so please let me know the method you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server acceps TCP socket connections you can use a web app communication over WebSockets, there is support for it in all major browsers today.

You need to be aware that WebSockets is not a raw TCP socket connection, and uses it's own protocoll on top of raw sockets, but it might be your best bet in connecting to your server without any browser plugins.